# How do I password protect a pdf document?

Tags: password, security, libreoffice, pdf

I have been sent one of those dreadful .pdf documents. I need to save it as 'password protected' how do I do that in LibreOffice?
There's lots of information on *creating* a password protected pdf document but I can find nothing on password protecting an existing .pdf.

Comment: To prevent what? You do know there are tools that simply remove the password from the pdf. You do not even need to know the password. "Advanced PDF Password Recovery" can "Instantly unlocks PDF documents with printing, copying and editing restrictions", "Removes “owner” and “user” passwords" and many more.

Comment: Just looked at this post again - my reply has gone missing. So: Thanks Rinzwind, didn't know that. "To prevent what?" - Good Q; sender instructed me to protect it. I shall look at pdftk suggested by six2dez once I've found out how much disc space it devours.

Comment: I might be better to ZIP the thing and put a sha512 pwd on the zip.

Comment: @Rinzwind: While weakly-encrypted (40 bit) PDFs can be decrypted, I think it's inaccurate to say that one can "simply remove" the password. [The product](https://www.elcomsoft.com/apdfpr.html) you mentioned doesn't claim to be unconditionally successful on 256-bit AES encryption either.

Comment: An attacker [can modify an encrypted PDF](https://usa.kaspersky.com/blog/36c3-pdf-encryption/21082/) so that its contents are sent to them (the attacker) when a user (who knows the password) opens it. This could happen when the file is sent e.g. by email.

Answer (score 23):

You can do this with `pdftk`. It is a powerful command line tool to manage PDFs.

```bash
pdftk source.pdf output destination.pdf user_pw password
```

Comment: Use `pdftk source.pdf output destination.pdf user_pw PROMPT` to have it ask you for a password. This is good practice, because it prevents the password from being visible in your shell history file and to other users and processes via `ps`.

Answer (score 12):

At the command line

```
qpdf --encrypt test123 test123 40 -- input.pdf doc_with_pass.pdf
```

Where test123 is both the user and owner password, the next value is for encryption key-length which may be 40, 128, or 256.

To decrypt the pdf file you can use the following

```
qpdf --password=test123 --decrypt doc_with_pass.pdf doc_without_pass.pdf
```

Comment: This is what I use to password protect (encrypt) PDF with 128-bit AES encryption (requires PDF v1.6):
"qpdf --encrypt user-password owner-password 128 --use-aes=y -- input.pdf doc_with_pass.pdf"

Comment: Is there a way to create a read-only file, no printing, without a password?

Answer (score 1):

To do this easily using the terminal command with my file named **HelpMe.PDF** :

(Note that I am using Ubuntu here)

1. Open Terminal and install PDFTK:
   `sudo apt install pdftk-java`
2. After installing locate the file.
   2a. If new to Linux: to do this go to the file and RIGHT CLICK>Click Properties>Under BASIC tab locate the line that says PARENT FOLDER [this is the location listed below of this example that says: "/home/UbuntuLaptop/"> then make sure you put the name of the file
   input this into the terminal.

(In this example I put my file in the documents folder)

`pdftk /home/UbuntuLaptop/Documents/HelpMe.pdf Output /home/UbuntuLaptop/Documents/HelpMePasswordProtected.pdf user_pw PROMPT`

in step 2 you can rename the file (as I did) to show which one is password protected when you open the file browser to locate it

3. The terminal command will give you a prompt to enter the password.  type your password and press enter
4. Browse for the location and open it to verify password