# How to make a PDF Form uneditable?

Tags: pdf

Is there a way I can fill out a PDF form in Ubuntu and safe it in a way that one cannot alter it longer? I remember there is such function on some other OS (e.g. macOS), but it seems like the Ubuntu document viewer is not able to do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I password protect a pdf document?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938015/how-do-i-password-protect-a-pdf-document)

Comment: Not quite, but the answer below does :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to get rid of the "fillable fields" in that form.

A way to do this is to convert the pdf into a jpg, and converting it back to a pdf.

To convert, enter the command

```
convert -density 300 /path/to/your/form.pdf picture.jpg
```

The `-density 300` ensures that the quality of the resulting JPG remains good.

Then convert it back to PDF with

```
convert /path/to/picture.jpg filename.pdf
```

The resulting PDF would not anymore have any fields to be filled.

Of course, someone may edit it in an image editor to change the contents.

*If someone can view the form, you cannot prevent them from editing it (even if it is password protected so that everyone can view, but only the people with password can edit, then one can take a screenshot and edit it with photo editing software like GIMP to change the contents).*

If you have problems converting it due to "security policies", follow the guideline here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998331/imagemagick-security-policy-pdf-blocking-conversion

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Its working. I had another problem converting it, but found a manual to fix that. I have added that to your answer if anybody falls over the same thing

Comment: @DORpapst Yes, now I remember, that is one of the first things I do after a new Ubuntu installation (I need to convert a lot of documents for making reports/presentations). This method used to work without any hassle until 2017 or so, after which they implemented this *stupid* security measure.